# segmentation fault when using PyQtChart

Tags: python, pyqt5

I just installed PyQtChart 5.7. However I suffered from segmentation fault when creating QChart object. My code is really simple like this.

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart

chart = QChart()
```

When I run it

```
[1]    27902 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an `QApplication` object.

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication
import sys

a = QApplication(sys.argv)
chart = QChart()

a.exec()
```

Comment: Thx, I just found it. :D